# update task using Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

Here's the library I'm using:
http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Install&referringTitle=Documentation

Here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var p = new Program();
      p.EnumAllTasks();

    }
    void EnumAllTasks() {
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        EnumFolderTasks(ts,ts.RootFolder);
    }

    void EnumFolderTasks(TaskService ts, TaskFolder fld) {
      var tasks = fld.Tasks.Where(t => t.Name.Equals("test-task", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

      foreach (Task task in tasks)
        ActOnTask(ts, task);
    }

    void ActOnTask(TaskService ts, Task t) {
      //ea.Path
      Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
      Console.WriteLine(t.Path);
      Console.WriteLine(((ExecAction)t.Definition.Actions.First()).Path);
      var ea = (ExecAction)t.Definition.Actions.First();

      ea.Path = ea.Path + ".coolio/test.exe";
      UpdateFirstAction(t, new ExecAction(ea.Path+".coolio/test.exe",ea.Arguments,ea.WorkingDirectory));
      //ts.s
      // Do something interesting here
    }

    void UpdateFirstAction(Task t, Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Action action) {
      if (t.TaskService.HighestSupportedVersion >= new Version(1, 2)) {
        Console.WriteLine("HERE");
        t.Definition.Actions.RemoveAt(0);
      }
      t.Definition.Actions.Add(action);
    }

  }
}
```

I added the 'UpdateFirstAction' method based upon the following: https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/discussions/203704

I want to be able to update the path that's getting executed, and the above link seems to imply that updating the collection is enough.

How do I actually *save* the changes?  All of the documentation I've read seems to describe how to read things only.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the UpdateFirstAction method. The library since version 1.6.1 has fixed the bug from that discussion item. The code is correct on how to edit the Path property. To update the task with the changed Path, you only need to call t.RegisterChanges() at the point you are calling UpdateFirstAction.